# Regex matching doesn't work even though the pattern is correct

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, capturing-group

It's been a few years since I've used regex, but if I remember correctly, the following should work:

```
String test = "axaxa";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-c])x\1x\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
```

m matches nothing on run. This is a super simplified version of what I'm doing in my code. That example is actually taken from a Java tutorial on regex! I tried to rewrite my html matching code from way back when it didn't work, I went to researching, thinking I did something wrong... which according to the Internet, I haven't. So. Does anyone have a clue as to why this doesn't work?

Extra info, `test.matches(the_pattern)` returns `false`. It seems like the group backtracking is messing it up.

Comment: Double your backslashes \\ not \

Answer (score 3):

Try using `\\1` in pace of `\1`.

`\` is the escape character in Java string. To send a `\1` to regex engine, we need to escape the `\` as `\\1`.

Comment: Thank you! It should've occurred to me that the string would eliminate \ before it's passed to the regex engine. Duh -.-

Answer (score 1):

In Java we have to *escape* the backslashes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-c])x\\1x\\1");
```